# Как поменять название программы в диспетчере задач?

Tags: c++, windows, ресурсы

Как сделать, чтобы диспетчер задач писал не скучное `myprog`, просто имя файла, а как для приличных программ - `Superprog of Mikhajlo`.

Как я понимаю, это где-то в ресурсах `VERSIONINFO`, но как не ковырялся, не могу этого добиться - `myprog` и все тут. Как выглядит минимальный пример такого .rc-файла, чтоб писал `Superprog`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Создаете файл ресурса .rc, открываете его в редакторе ресурсов, щелкаете правой кнопкой -> Добавить ресурс -> Version. Редактируете поле File Description, сохраняете, компилируете[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

получается вот так

Прикладываю Resource.rc, сгенерированный вижаком

```
// Microsoft Visual C++ generated resource script.
//
#include "resource1.h"

#define APSTUDIO_READONLY_SYMBOLS
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Generated from the TEXTINCLUDE 2 resource.
//
#include "winres.h"

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#undef APSTUDIO_READONLY_SYMBOLS

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Русский (Россия) resources

#if !defined(AFX_RESOURCE_DLL) || defined(AFX_TARG_RUS)
LANGUAGE LANG_RUSSIAN, SUBLANG_DEFAULT
#pragma code_page(1251)

#ifdef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// TEXTINCLUDE
//

1 TEXTINCLUDE 
BEGIN
    "resource1.h\0"
END

2 TEXTINCLUDE 
BEGIN
    "#include ""winres.h""\r\n"
    "\0"
END

3 TEXTINCLUDE 
BEGIN
    "\r\n"
    "\0"
END

#endif    // APSTUDIO_INVOKED


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Version
//

VS_VERSION_INFO VERSIONINFO
 FILEVERSION 1,0,0,1
 PRODUCTVERSION 1,0,0,1
 FILEFLAGSMASK 0x3fL
#ifdef _DEBUG
 FILEFLAGS 0x1L
#else
 FILEFLAGS 0x0L
#endif
 FILEOS 0x40004L
 FILETYPE 0x1L
 FILESUBTYPE 0x0L
BEGIN
    BLOCK "StringFileInfo"
    BEGIN
        BLOCK "041904b0"
        BEGIN
            VALUE "CompanyName", "TODO: <Название компании>"
            VALUE "FileDescription", "kek"
            VALUE "FileVersion", "1.0.0.1"
            VALUE "InternalName", "C++proj"
            VALUE "LegalCopyright", "Copyright (C) 2020"
            VALUE "OriginalFilename", "C++proj.exe"
            VALUE "ProductName", "TODO: <Имя продукта>"
            VALUE "ProductVersion", "1.0.0.1"
        END
    END
    BLOCK "VarFileInfo"
    BEGIN
        VALUE "Translation", 0x419, 1200
    END
END

#endif    // Русский (Россия) resources
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////



#ifndef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Generated from the TEXTINCLUDE 3 resource.
//


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#endif    // not APSTUDIO_INVOKED
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Примерно вот так

Comment: Можете привести полный текст этого .rc-файла? А то я это делал, но не получилось. Видимо, что-то не написал...

Comment: Завтра с работы приведу ,если будет актуально еще

Comment: @Mikhailo отредактировал ответ, добавил файл

Comment: Тогда, наверное, понятно. Я пробовал ограничиться только FileDescription, а оказыввается, минимальный файл должен содержать все, включая копирайты и какие-то Translation... Грустно. Неужели короче - никак нельзя?

Comment: Да почему, можете закомментировать все VALUE операторы в блоке ```StringFileInfo```, и все равно получите желаемый результат. Только закомментировав блок ```VarFileInfo``` в диспетчере задач снова пропало название, так что его стоит оставить. Показал еще в одной картинке в ответе