# Как сделать описание своей программы в диспетчере задач?

Tags: c++, windows, диспетчер-задач

Недавно начал интересоваться программированием на языке `с++`. Меня очень интересует такой вопрос о том как можно сделать описание своей программы? И еще, можно ли его как то изменить в чужой программе не имея при этом её исходников?

Пример описания программы:

[image: Пример]

Comment: У вас два вопроса в одном, исправьте.

Comment: @andreymal так вопросы максимально близки друг к другу, разве нет?

Comment: @ПавелЕриков неа, максимально далеки. Писать свою программу и вмешиваться в чужую программу — это две категорически разные вещи

Comment: @andreymal неа автор подразумевает не вмешивание в чужую программу, а просто как например через код элемента на сайте что-то поменять. Например на WinAPI можно спокойно в меню другой программы добавлять вкладку. Я к тому, что автор хочет узнать как в целом делать это не только для своей программы. И по этому лучше задать два таких вопроса чем в 1 предложение один вопрос,  а потом другой, ну или же задать вопрос по типу "Как изменить описание программы?".

Comment: Это не то же, о чем [спрашивал я](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1218227/228791)?

Comment: http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/

Answer (score 1):

Если ваша вы пишите код в `Visual Studio`, то самый простой способ это добавить файл ресурса `Version`. Для этого откройте `Обозреватель решений` и при нажатии правой кнопкой мыши нажмите `Добавить -> Ресурс -> Version` далее найдите в самой левой колонке `Ключ` ключ `FileVersion` и измените значение.

Для примера приведу скрин:
[image: Пример]

Вот результат:
[image: Результат]

Или можете сами создать файл ресурсов. Пример можете посмотреть [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1022449/how-to-change-an-executables-properties-windows)

К сожалению не знаю, как изменить другой программе описание. Попробую узнать или найти информацию и дополнить ответ.